# Focus frame on buttons Material-UI v.1.0.0

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I changed the version of the library to `v1.0.0-beta.21` from `v.0.19`
And now all buttons have a focus frame. For example
[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVfps.png)
[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwSab.png)

How can I hide this frame?

Comment: please share some code, especially the props that are passed to the `Button` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using css, something like `button:focus {outline:0;}` should work. Although you should consider re-styling the outline rather than hiding it for the sake of accessibility.

Comment: Is there a way to set this from within Material UI? Having this focus frame seems to be the default behavior.